# Display errors for software sales java

Tags: java

For this code i want for it to display **"Your discount is $  ."Your total is $  ."** when `sales >= 10`  but when its less than 10 i want it to display **"No discount. Your total is  $."

the problem is that whatever number i enter it keeps saying **"No discount. Your total $  ."** and it does the calculations. anyhelp will be very much appreciated it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class SoftwareSales
    {
       public static void main(String[] args)
       {

          Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

          int sales = 99;

          int quantity;
          double total;
          double rate = 0;
          double discount;

          System.out.print ("Enter amount of packages purchased: ");
                quantity = keyboard.nextInt();

          total = quantity * sales;
          discount = total * rate;
          total = total - discount;

          if (sales < 10) {
                if (sales >= 10 || sales <= 19)  
                    rate = 0.20;  
                else if (sales >= 20 || sales <=49)  
                    rate = 0.30;  
                else if (sales >= 50 || sales <=99)  
                    rate = 0.40;  
                else if (sales > 100)  
                    rate = 0.50;  
                System.out.println("Your discount is $" + (int)discount + 
                                       ". Your total is: $" + (int)total);
          } else {

                    System.out.print("No discount. " + 
                                     "Your total is: $" + (int)total);
    }
       }
    }
```

Comment: This isn't actually an answer to the quetsion, but shouldn't those if statements be `if (sales >= 10 && sales <= 19)` with an and, not an or?

Comment: For all of them? @Tharwen

Comment: Yeah. Also, `sales` is always 99. You never change the value.

Comment: I already set `int sales = 99;`

and yeah you're right its `&&` thanks! but still do you know how to fix my problem ive tried alot of things for the past few days ^^;

Comment: Yes, but you never change it from 99 afterwards. Your if statement expects the value to be variable but it's always 99, so only the `else` block can ever execute.

Comment: Nvm i get it now my bad ^^;

Comment: Sorry i made a few corrections. it was suppose to be quantity not sales. once again can you check it because i still have the same problem

Comment: I've posted an answer with all the changes in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues. The main one is that you're relying on the value of `sales`, which you never change. It looks like you meant to use `quantity` instead, which the user entered:

```
if (quantity< 10) {
    if (quantity >= 10 || quantity <= 19)
        rate = 0.20;
    else if (quantity >= 20 || quantity <=49)
        rate = 0.30;
    else if (quantity >= 50 || quantity <=99)
        rate = 0.40;
    else if (quantity > 100)  
        rate = 0.50;
```

The second problem is that your if statement is the wrong way round. As it is, you're only applying a discount if the user entered less than 10, which doesn't make sense. Change it to use a greater-than-or-equal operator:

```
if (quantity >= 10) {
```

You're also using OR operators in the if/else-ifs when it looks like ANDs would work better. Switch them like this:

```
if (sales >= 10 && sales <= 19)
    rate = 0.20;
else if (sales >= 20 && sales <=49)
    rate = 0.30;
else if (sales >= 50 && sales <=99)
    rate = 0.40;
```

Finally, you're not actually applying `rate` to `discount` after you calculate it. You have the calculation higher up, when `rate` still equals 0. Move it down below the if statements to make it work:

```
if (quantity >= 10) {
    if (quantity >= 10 && quantity <= 19)  
        rate = 0.20;  
    else if (quantity >= 20 && quantity <=49)  
        rate = 0.30;  
    else if (quantity >= 50 && quantity <=99)  
        rate = 0.40;  
    else if (quantity > 100)  
        rate = 0.50;  

    discount = total * rate;
    total = total - discount;

    System.out.println("Your discount is $" + (int)discount + 
        ". Your total is: $" + (int)total);
} else {

    System.out.print("No discount. " + 
        "Your total is: $" + (int)total);
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! Now i get what i did wrong!! Thanks for your time and you help. it is VERY much appreciated. Have a wonderful day!

Answer (score 1):

all you have to do is change 
    `if (sales < 10)`

into

```
if (sales > 10)
```

which is the main problem and then change the sales quantity somehow

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort!

Answer (score 1):

I think that immediately below your computation of `total`

```
if (sales < 10) {
```

should be

```
if (sales >= 10) {
```

as in your question.

But also, `sales == 99` no matter what is entered?  Maybe you want

```
    if (total >= 10) {
```

?  And why compute `rate` if you're not using it?

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort!

Answer (score 1):

you have initialized `sales` to `99`.

```
int sales = 99;
```

So the condtion `sales < 10` is always giving `false`.So `if` block never executes.
You need to change the condition

```
sales<10
```

to

```
sales>10
```

to execute if block .

Comment: Ohhhhhhhh ok ok ok so how would i fix that. if you can guide me?

Comment: @user2771077 Updated my answer.Please look into it.

Comment: Sorry i made a few corrections. it was suppose to be quantity not sales. once again can you check it because i still have the same problem

Comment: @user2771077 same problem then same solution ;).Just change `if (quantity < 10)` to `if (quantity > 10)`

Comment: I have that now but it sill just keeps on giving me no discount when i enter anything above 10

Comment: No it should not.Please recompile and run it.I have executed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is already given by @tharwen your code should be like this

```
if (quantity >= 10) {
  if (quantity>= 10 || quantity<= 19)  {
    rate = 0.20;  
  } else if (quantity >= 20 || quantity <=49) {
    rate = 0.30;  
  } else if (quantity >= 50 || quantity <=99) {
    rate = 0.40;  
  } else if (quantity > 100) {
    rate = 0.50;
  }
  System.out.println("Your discount is $" + (int)discount + ". Your total is: $" + (int)total);
  } else {
    System.out.print("No discount. " + "Your total is: $" + (int)total);
  }
```

Comment: I have all that but it keeps saying no discount whenever i enter anything above 10

Comment: your condition in the first `if` statement is wrong. when `quantity >=10` other checks should be done `else System.out.print("No discount. " + "Your total is: $" + (int)total);`